# How can I put a margin on a label?

Tags: react-native, textfield

I need to put a margin just on a label; How can I do that?
I've been trying many things.

```js
<TextField
  className="w-full"
  id="name"
  type="text"
  disabled
  name="name"
  label="Company name"
  value={name || ''}
  onChange={(event) => setName(event.target.value)}
  validations={{ minLength: 2, maxLength: 100 }}
  validationErrors={{
    isDefaultRequiredValue: 'Company name is required',
    minLength: 'Company name must contain at least 2 characters',
    maxLength: 'Company name must contain at most 100 characters',
  }}
  variant="filled"
  required
/>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take the [tour] (and earn a badge) - Also read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve this question.  Also, can you clarify what you mean by adding a margin to a label? (right margin? left? top? bottom? all?)

Comment: Add `padding` to your `TextField`.